# Extracting multiple occurrences in line without known separator using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a large text file that contains probabilities embedded in sentences. I want to extract only those probabilities and the text before them. Example

Input:

```
not interesting
foo is 1 in 1,200 and test is 1 in 3.4 not interesting
something else is 1 in 2.5, things are 1 in 10
also not interesting
```

Wanted output:

```
foo is 1/1,200
and test is 1/3.4
something else is 1/2.5,
things are 1/10
```

What I have so far:

```
$ sed -nr ':a s|(.*) 1 in ([0-9.,]+)|\1 1/\2\n|;tx;by; :x h;ba; :y g;/^$/d; p' input

foo is 1/1,200
 and test is 1/3.4
 not interesting
something else is 1/2.5,
 things are 1/10

something else is 1/2.5,
 things are 1/10
```

This *beautiful* code repeatedly splits lines when it matches, and tries to only print it if it contained matches. The problem with my code seems to be that the hold space isn't cleared after a line is done.

The general problem is that sed can't do non-greedy matching and my separator can be anything.

I guess a solution in a different language would be okay, but now I'm kind of intrigued if this is possible in sed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]) in ([0-9]\S*\s*)/\1\/\2\n/;/[0-9]\/[0-9]/P;D' file
```

This replaces some number followed by space followed by `in` followed by a space followed by a token beginning with a number followed by a possible space with the first number followed by a `/` followed by the second token beginning with a number followed by a new line. If the following line contains a number followed by a /` followed by a number, then print it and then delete it and if anything else is in the pattern space repeat.

Answer (score 5):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, that is all. For anything more interesting just use awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    while ( match($0,/\s*([^0-9]+)([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9,.]+)/,a) ) {
        print a[1] a[2] "/" a[3]
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }
}
$ awk -f tst.awk file
foo is 1/1,200
and test is 1/3.4
something else is 1/2.5,
things are 1/10
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) can do it, although it's not the best tool for the job. My attempt is to search all `number in number` pattern and add a newline after each one. Then remove trailing text (no newline after it), remove leading spaces and print:

```
sed -nr '/([0-9]+) in ([0-9,.]+)/ { s//\1\/\2\n/g; s/\n[ ]*/\n/g; s/\n[^\n]*$//; p }' file
```

It yields:

```
foo is 1/1,200
and test is 1/3.4
something else is 1/2.5,
things are 1/10
```

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty neat and seems to do exactly what I wanted

Comment: I don't see that this solution yields what was required.

Comment: right, the `x in y` -> `x/y` is missing. It solved what I had difficulty with; I just added another sed call after that one. I changed the accepted answer to the other one

Comment: @potong: Thank you. Already fixed, using `\1` and `\2` instead of `&`.